# Showing that $p_0$ and $p_1$ are homotopic

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

How would you show that for two loops $p_0$ and $p_1$ in $S^n$, such that for all $t \in [0,1]$, $p_0(t) \neq -p_1(t)$, we have that $p_0$ and $p_1$ are endpoint preserving homotopic?

Comment: Deform $p_0$ toward $p_1$ by moving each point $p_0(t)$ toward the point $p_1(t)$ along the shorter of the two great-circle arcs joining these two points.  Your assumption that $p_0(t)\neq-p_1(t)$ ensures that "shorter" is well-defined.

Comment: but how can we simply move each point?

Comment: I should have said to move the points at constant speed. You get, for each $t$, a path $z_t:[0,1]\to S^n$ with $z_t(0)=p_0(t)$ and $z_t(1)=p_1(t)$. Then check that $(s,t)\mapsto z_s(t)$ is a homotopy from $p_0$ to $p_1$.  The main point is to check that it's continuous in both variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$\begin{matrix}f\colon&[0,1]\times[0,1]&\to&\mathbb R^{n+1}\\&(x,t)&\mapsto&(1-x)p_0(t)+xp_1(t)\end{matrix}$$
is continuous and avoids $0$ (why?), so that we obtain a homotopy
$$\begin{matrix}H\colon&[0,1]\times[0,1]&\to&\mathbb S^{n}\\&(x,t)&\mapsto&\frac{f(x,t)}{|f(x,t)|}.\end{matrix}$$